# Convert JSON String to JSON object using json.dumps in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON String as

```
{
    "zone1" : 
    [
        {
            "detected_people" : 
            {
                "coordinates" : 
                [
                    [
                        22,
                        3
                    ],
                    [
                        21,
                        6
                    ],
                    [
                        16,
                        21
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "gridOrigin" : 
            [
                28.5,
                20.600000000000001
            ],
            "gridScale" : 0.5,
            "gridSizeX" : 50,
            "gridSizeY" : 50,
            "stamp" : "2020-08-28 22:23:05",
            "zoneID" : "shop1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I convert to JSON object using json.dumps

```
  info=data.decode("utf-8")
  print(info)
  json_obj = json.dumps(info)
  print(type(json_obj))
  print(json_obj)
```

I have a lot of `\t` and type is still `<class 'str'>`

```
"{\n\t\"zone1\" : \n\t[\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"detected_people\" : \n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\"coordinates\" : \n\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t22,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t3\n\t\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t21,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t6\n\t\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t\t\t16,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t21\n\t\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\"gridOrigin\" : \n\t\t\t[\n\t\t\t\t28.5,\n\t\t\t\t20.600000000000001\n\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\"gridScale\" : 0.5,\n\t\t\t\"gridSizeX\" : 50,\n\t\t\t\"gridSizeY\" : 50,\n\t\t\t\"stamp\" : \"2020-08-28 22:23:05\",\n\t\t\t\"zoneID\" : \"shop1\"\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}"
```

How to convert my JSON string `info` to JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.loads` instead of `json.dumps`:

```
info=data.decode("utf-8")
print(info)
json_obj = json.loads(info)
print(type(json_obj))
print(json_obj)
```

Output

```
{
    "zone1" :
    [
        {
            "detected_people" :
...........
            "zoneID" : "shop1"
        }
    ]
}

<class 'dict'>
{'zone1': [{'detected_people': {'coordinates': [[22, 3], [21, 6], [16, 21]]}, 'gridOrigin': [28.5, 20.6], 'gridScale': 0.5, 'gridSizeX': 50, 'gridSizeY': 50, 'stamp': '2020-08-28 22:23:05', 'zoneID': 'shop1'}]}
```